# Anylogic Mean rate lost customer

Tags: anylogic

I have a model where the queue's capacity limit is 2. I also set up a "SelectOutput"-block before the queue, as customers who can't enter the queue are lost. So now I want to find out the mean rate at which customers are lost? How can I do that?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable `leftLastMin` of type int.

In the "on exit (false)" code of the SelectOutput, write `leftLastMin ++`

Now, create a recurring event that triggers every minute. Here, you can easily do something with the number left last minute (traceln, store into dataset or statistics object...).

Also, reset your counter `leftLastMin=0` so it is ready for the next minute.